# OpenCV 3.0.0 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.0

I am trying to set up Eclipse (Neon version) with OpenCV 3.0.0 and I ran into an issue.
When I am loading an image, the code below:

```
Mat m = Imgcodecs.imread("newimage.jpg");
```

the following error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(Imgcodecs.java:82)
    at TestOpenCVFeats.main(TestOpenCVFeats.java:39)
```

Everything is set up according to this site
[Set up OpenCV for Java in Eclipse](http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html#set-up-opencv-for-java-in-eclipse)

Also added the path to java.library.path with:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/share/OpenCV/java
```

confirmed it is there with:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties
```

and to the $PATH variable.

Also added this command to JVM run configuration:

```
-Djava.library.path= "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/java"
```

Also tried with this line of code and without it:

```
System.loadLibrary("libopencv_java300");
```

The permissions for the files on the path /usr/local/share/OpenCV/java are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 831809 Srp  1  2015 libopencv_java300.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 300815 Srp  1  2015 opencv-300.jar
```

I have tried all possible combinations and still get the same error.
I do not know what else I could try to make this work.
The OpenCV works properly when I execute the c++ (Eclipse Luna) or python code. 
My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, well, found the solution.
This line of code needs to be added in main:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure OpenCV in windows using eclipse follow these steps:

1. Download OpenCV 2.4.11 or any version from this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.11/opencv-2.4.11.exe/download
2. Extract it.
3. Open eclipse.
4. Create a new Java Project.
5. Add the OpenCV jar.

   - Right click on the project.
   - Choose Build Path.
   - Click Configure Build Path.
   - Click Libraries.
   - Add External Jars.
   - Open OpenCV extracted folder.
   - Open build/java/
   - Choose opencv-2411.jar and open.
   - Click Apply.
   - Click Ok.
6. Add Native Library.

---

You can use OpenCv Native Library by:

- Adding the native library to your opencv jar.
- Point to Native Library in java by using System.load() methods, but make sure you have to specify the native library path.

---

Adding the native library to your opencv jar

- Right click on the project.
- Choose Build Path.
- Click Configure Build Path.
- Click Libraries.
- Expand opencv jar.
- Click Native Library.
- Click Edit button in the right side panel.
- Click External Folde.
- Open OpenCV extracted folder.
- Open build/java/x64.(if your OS is 64bit choose x64 else x86)
- Click Ok.
- Click Apply.
- Click Ok.

---

Point to Native Library in java class

- Pass the location of "opencv_java2411.dll" from opencv\build\java\x64 to System.load("Path of your opencv dll")